# Typeorm causes Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, typescript, memory-leaks, nestjs, typeorm

im coding a backend for a customer of mine with which he is able to manage his film's and filmlicenses.

im using nestjs and typeorm for this task.

i got this function

```js
async getMovieById(id: number) {

        const movie = await this.moviesRepository
            .createQueryBuilder('movie')
            .where('movie.id = :id', { id })
            .leftJoinAndSelect('movie.actors', 'actors')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('movie.pressReleases', 'pressReleases')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('movie.crewMembers', 'crewMembers')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('movie.festivals', 'festivals')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('movie.stills', 'stills')
            .getOne();
        if (!movie) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        return movie;
}
```

for some movies it returns everything how it is supposed to but on some other movies typeorm just eats the memory, almost as if it is in an infinite loop and ends in a memory leak.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[25584:00000209050A0080]   179956 ms: Mark-sweep 2042.9 (2052.9) -> 2042.4 (2054.4) MB, 183.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.505, current mu = 0.049) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[25584:00000209050A0080]   180149 ms: Mark-sweep 2044.4 (2058.4) -> 2043.8 (2059.4) MB, 177.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.349, current mu = 0.082) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: Your query looks correct code-wise. If you already know the id of the movie that causes the failure, I would recommend you debug the query by doing one of the following:
1. Rewrite the query using raw SQL and see how it behaves.
2. Validating that your entities and their nested entities are properly specified.
3. Removing joins one by one until the query passes and then investigating the specific join that causes the failure.